# Set 'fs' to empty or false does not help browser-pack inside browserify to run on the web

Tags: javascript, webpack, browserify

Do you guys know why this package [**browser-pack**](https://github.com/browserify/browser-pack) was designed to work with [**browserify**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) but its [index.js](https://github.com/browserify/browser-pack/blob/master/index.js) uses `fs` and `path`?

I have the same question for **browserify** itself as well after I found **browserify** does use `fs` in its index.js file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var combineSourceMap = require('combine-source-map');

var defaultPreludePath = path.join(__dirname, '_prelude.js');
var defaultPrelude = fs.readFileSync(defaultPreludePath, 'utf8');
```

I do not use CLI to run those, I run **browserify** through its API support like below when clicking a button on the Web UI:

```
import browserify from 'browserify';

const rs = browserify(fileContentStreams, opts)
   .transform('brfs')
   .transform(sassify, {
       base64Encode: false,
       sourceMap: false
   }) ...

...
```

Since **browserify** already stated that:

> **Browserify** is an open-source JavaScript tool that allows developers to write Node. js-style modules that compile for use in the browser. Browserify lets you use require in the browser, the same way you'd use it in Node. It's not just syntactic sugar for loading scripts on the client.

I cannot use **Browserify** on the *browser side*, and I did try as following in `webpack.config.js` but it throws errors anyway:

`node: { fs: 'empty' }`

or

`node: { fs: false }`

The former option throws `fs.readFileSync is not a function` while a long chain of errors were thrown for the latter since `fs.readFileSync` is used in `browser-pack`.

These are the errors after `webpack` build was completed:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/browserify/index.js 396:16-30
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/module-deps/index.js 302:20-32
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/browserify/index.js
```